# setting up a mouse loop mac server, dual monitor client

Tags: mouse, synergy

I'm trying to set up Synergy 1.4 in a format that resembles:

Win7Client monitor 1 | MacServer Monitor | Win7Client monitor 2

Is this possible? I was able to set it up in the past with Windows being the server and mac being the client, but having a broken shift key was annoying. I figured I would try it this way, but the GUI monitor set up doesn't allow for screen with duplicate names. I tried to find a conf file I could edit that was created by the GUI, but had no luck.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior isn't supported because for the purposes of screen edges **Synergy treats each client as a single rectangle regardless of how many monitors it has**. Using your example: there is no "edge" between Win-Monitor-1, and Win-Monitor-2.

*However* there is a workaround to 'fake it': create a loop, and put the outside two monitors (attached to the dual-head machine) on the *wrong sides*.

In `synergy.conf`:

```
section: links
    mac:
        right = win
        left = win
    win:
        left = mac
        right = mac
end
```

Another alternative is to connect the bottom edge of the mac to the top edge of the windows machine. This may seem conceptually strange at first but it quickly becomes quite natural.